# How to use PHP Array in MySQL Select statement with IN?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have an array and I wrote this code which does not work. Could someone help me with this query? Thanks a lot!

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`Productcode` IN (".$array.") ";
         $result=mysql_query($sql);
         if(!$result)die('not exist');
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on the `$array`.

Comment: -1 Because, according to comments, this table doesn't even exist in your database. You'd failed to do proper error checking and therefore only just found out. Also "does not work" is horribly useless.

Comment: @darya wow this goes straight in my top 10 of worst askers in StackOverflow. Congrats!

Comment: thanks i found my error . thanks alot:)

Answer (score 1):

the array should be a string

```
$string = implode("','", $array);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`Productcode` IN ('".$string."') ";
```

quotes not needed if the productcode is an integer

Comment: Note the quotes aren't needed if the array contains integers.

Comment: when i wrote this , i have error !!!

Comment: and  if(!$result)die('not exist'); display in my webpage ??

Comment: @Darya instead of `die('not exists')` write `die(mysql_error())` and tell us what do you see

Comment: i see this :   Table 'final.product' doesn't exist

Comment: don't find my product table in mysqlserver

Comment: @Darya Now you have the information you need to debug your code. Good luck.

Comment: @Darya are you serious? dammit!

Comment: thanks i found my error . thanks alot:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your array is not multidimentional

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`Productcode` IN ('".implode("',", $array)."') ";
```

Comment: Your implode argument is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `implode()` the array to a string (presuming your `$array` is actually an array):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`Productcode` IN ('" . implode("', '", $array) . "')";
```

Comment: when i wrote this , i have error !!! 
and if(!$result)die('not exist'); display not exist in my webpage ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to implode the array to a comma separated list before it can be used IN()

```
IN(".implode(',',$array).")
```